# How To Make My Form Respond to Ctrl-Alt, in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I have a simple Form in C#, that has a Grid and several Buttons.

I want the form to change its GUI a bit, when Ctrl-Alt is pressed,
and to have the GUI reverted back to original when Ctrl-Alt is released.

I know how to check if Ctrl+Alt is pressed - one way to do it is via Control.ModifierKeys.

What I ask is this:

For button press, I have Event Handler that respond to it.
For the Keyboard regular Keys I have Event Handler that respond to it.
But Ctrl-Alt are not a regular key - they do not raise an event when pressed.

So what should I do?

One way I thought about, is to enable a Timer that will run, and check every 200ms if Ctrl-Alt is pressed.

Is there a better way than a Timer?

Thank you

Comment: Check in KeyDown. But this is terrible idea. How will user press ctrl+alt+del without triggering your action? These are modifier keys. Other than in a full screen game they should only mean something in conjunction with a non modifier key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably override the Form's method to pick up the keystroke.

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)    
 {
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Alt ) 
    {
       //Do Stuff here
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg,keyData);
 }
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, this is going to frustrate users.  Forcibly acting upon _every key combination_ containing `Control` and `Alt`?  And likely short-circuiting other valid needs?  Ugh.